# How to detect taps on image(s) attached in an attributedString and get image(s)' position in it?

Tags: swift, image, position

In my app, images added into an attributedString, and I need to detect the images' position and do something when images tapped, the images stored in core data, once the image "deleted" in attributedString (actually in textView), the current deleted image will be deleted from the core data.

How can I make like tags for each image when image picked?

The code for now:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    okSaveBtn.enabled = true

    imageArray.append(image)

    let theString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)

    let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let newImage = image.resizeImage(image, newWidth: 150)

    imageAttachment.image = newImage

    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)

    theString.appendAttributedString(imageString)

    // just trying to figure out the relationship between entered string and picked images

    let txt = (theString.string as NSString).rangeOfString(textView.text)
    print("txt length : \(txt.length)")
    print("txt location : \(txt.location)")


    textView.attributedText = theString
    // ================================================================

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    /* remark
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
        self.hintLabel.hidden = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.hintLabel.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in

                // Fade out
                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                    self.hintLabel.alpha = 0
                    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                        self.hintLabel.hidden = true
                })
        })

    }
    */
}
```